# Unity - Mesh Deforms terribly while mixing animations

Tags: c#, unity, animation

I have a simple game I'm working on to help me learn unity3d. In my Start() function, I've used the following code to set up my animations.

```
        walkAnimation = animation["Walk"];
        walkAnimation.layer = 1;
        walkAnimation.blendMode = AnimationBlendMode.Additive;
        walkAnimation.enabled = true;
        walkAnimation.wrapMode = WrapMode.Loop;

        walkBackwardsAnimation = animation["WalkBackwards"];
        walkBackwardsAnimation.layer = 0;
        walkBackwardsAnimation.blendMode = AnimationBlendMode.Additive;
        walkBackwardsAnimation.enabled = true;
        walkBackwardsAnimation.wrapMode = WrapMode.Loop;

        TurnLeftAnimation = animation["TurnLeft"];
        TurnLeftAnimation.layer = 1;
        TurnLeftAnimation.blendMode = AnimationBlendMode.Additive;
        TurnLeftAnimation.enabled = true;
        TurnLeftAnimation.wrapMode = WrapMode.Loop;

        TurnRightAnimation = animation["TurnRight"];
        TurnRightAnimation.layer = 1;
        TurnRightAnimation.blendMode = AnimationBlendMode.Additive;
        TurnRightAnimation.enabled = true;
        TurnRightAnimation.wrapMode = WrapMode.Loop;
```

Each of them are declared before start like this

```
public AnimationState walkAnimation;
```

and I call them depending on the values of the control's axis, like such;

```
if(Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxis("Rotate Player")) > 0){
                if (Input.GetAxis("Rotate Player") > 0){
                    animation.CrossFade(TurnRightAnimation.name, 0.2f);
                }
```

The problem is, The animations don't play, and when I turn while moving my character deforms gruesomely, his arms rise above his head and into his body, other parts grow, etc

I've been battling with mixing animations for the last two weeks, but I'm determined to get it right. If you know anything about this problem please don't hesitate to tell me what it might be. I created the model myself as well, all animations are on a single mesh, and I've tried to make the different animations affect different bones.

Comment: You can't get a animation to play stand alone and you're worried about mixing animations? Have implemented your code from a known good example? Try getting a single animation to play correctly before blending animations.

Comment: I've gotten my animations to play alone. I just can't get them to mix

Comment: What I mean is that they don't play when mixing